# cannot create database as root in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, vps

I just got my VPS, I login to phpmyadmin as root but I cannot create a database, I can't even see a link for this. I also want to change other user's permissions but I cannot find out how to.

Comment: what version of mysql/apache do you have?

Comment: mysql server 5.1.45

Comment: This is configurable in phpMyAdmin’s `config.inc.php`. The setting is called `ShowCreateDb`. Do you have access to your phpMyAdmin configuration file? If not, there’s probably no way to fix this.

Comment: how can i access this file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably something you need to talk to your VPS about, standard PhpMyAdmin installs under root contain links for creating Databases, they are probably using a modified PMA for VPS.

Comment: i can only create database from cpnael user account, thats really annoying

Comment: Annoying is cPanel's middle name, lol.